# How do I count conditionally in R

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements

I have a list

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

How do I count how many elements are over 3. So the output would be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact logical are represented by 1 and 0
`sum(1:5 > 3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
x <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
sum( x > 3 )
#Output: [1] 2
```